# reactjs container component form values

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am new to react and am trying to get the value from the firstName input in handleSubmit.  handleSubmit is working but for some reason the input value is undefined.  I tried following some other examples but they were all forms in React components.

```
let SomeForm = (props) => {

  let firstName = '';

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(firstName);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <TextField
          floatingLabelText="First Name"
          floatingLabelFixed={true}
          underlineStyle={styles.underlineStyle}
          underlineFocusStyle={styles.underlineFocusStyle}
          value={firstName}
        />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}
SomeForm = connect()(SomeForm)

export default SomeForm
```

Comment: Where is the TextField from? And it seems you didn't update your firstName at all

Comment: TextField is just from Material UI, is that what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `onChange` to the `TextField` to handle the updates. And because `SomeForm` is a stateful component, you may need to use a `class` component instead of a stateless functional component.

```
class SomeForm extends React.Component {
  state = {
    firstName: ''
  };

  handleChange = (e, value) => {
    this.setState({ firstName: value });
  };

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state.firstName);
  };

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <TextField
            id="text-field-controlled"
            floatingLabelText="First Name"
            floatingLabelFixed={true}
            underlineStyle={styles.underlineStyle}
            underlineFocusStyle={styles.underlineFocusStyle}
            value={this.state.firstName}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

See the API and examples of `TextField` here: http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/text-field

Comment: thanks, makes sense, I shouldn't have done that as a container

Answer (score 1):

You need function that you will throw in your TextField component and with onChange you can get value of input.

```
handleChange(e){
     Console.log(e.target.value)
}
```

And in TextField

```
<TextField onChange={this.handleCahnge}/}
```

Or use refs

```
<TextField ref="textfield" />
```

And get value with `this.refs.textfield.getValue()`